# What is the Best Introduction to Dedekind Cuts?

Tags: reference-request, irrational-numbers, real-numbers, rational-numbers, foundations

I'm looking for a clear, thorough, and easy-to-follow introduction to Dedekind cuts that is specifically geared towards those with an interest in foundational issues.  So far, the discussions that I have found within analysis textbooks range from a brief two-page exposition to highly condensed nine-step proof.  Most importantly, I'm looking for elucidating diagrams and a detailed explanation of Dedekind's motivating intuitions.

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions!

Comment: Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" begins with this - perhaps worth a look.

Comment: Why not "Continuity and Irrational Numbers" by Richard Dedekind? It is freely available from http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21016 and I am pretty sure you will not find it very demanding.